# understanding if check on PHILE_CLI_MODE

Tags: php

I was just going through the code of **[PhileCMS](https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile/blob/master/lib/Phile/Core/Session.php#L33)** and came across the following line of code:

```
if (PHILE_CLI_MODE) {
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '127.0.0.1';
}
```

Now what is PHILE_CLI_MODE and where is this variable coming from, i don't see it declared in the script **[HERE](https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile/blob/master/lib/Phile/Core/Session.php#L33)**.

Can anybody tell me where this variable is coming from ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's being set in `lib/Phile/Bootstrap.php`, line 79.

```
defined('PHILE_CLI_MODE')   or define('PHILE_CLI_MODE',  (php_sapi_name() == "cli") ? true : false);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a variable, it's a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) defined in [lib/Phile/Bootstrap.php](https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile/tree/master/lib/Phile/Bootstrap.php#L79)

```
defined('PHILE_CLI_MODE')   or define('PHILE_CLI_MODE',  (php_sapi_name() == "cli") ? true : false);
```

This file is included everytime in the root [index.php](https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile/tree/master/index.php#L9)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/Phile/Bootstrap.php';
```

The constant PHILE_CLI_MODE indicates with the help of [php_sapi_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php), if Phile is run via the [command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) (CLI = [Command-line interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)) or via a web browser (then it's `FALSE`).

In the end, if Phile is run via the command line and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is not set, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is set to 127.0.0.1 (=[localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost))